# How to show all files extensions in Eclipse tabs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I'm using Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu and need it to show all my file extensions on the top of every open tab. Currently, on CDT it shows all file extensions for C files but hides the extensions for some other file types (specifically Cython files).

For example: on tab's file title instead of "calibration.pyx" I see just "calibration".

When I go to Window->preferrences I can't find a solution. Anyone with an idea?

Comment: Are you sure they are hidden and not just invisible due to file name length? Also, are you using a special editor for those files? What if you right click a file in the project exporer, select "Open with" > "Text Editor"?

Comment: I see the file name but the extension is hidden. The file name is not too long: "calibration.pyx" and what I see is just "calibration"

Comment: Each of the many different editors in Eclipse makes its own choice of what is shown as the title in the tab, there is no centralized control of this.

Comment: When I choose to open the file with text editor it does show me the file name with extension.

Answer (score 2):

Today I noticed the same thing on a particular Eclipse installation, for Python files. Solution: go into the preferences (Window -> Prferences). Select "PyDev" in the tree on the left. Open "Pydev" and navigate into "Pydev ->Editor _. Editor Caption/Icon. Select "Editor Caption/Icon". On the right had side, check "Show file extension on tab?". That's it. Apply and close the preferences. Of course, this requires "PyDev" to be par of the Eclipse installation, but without something like "PyDev" the question is not applicable. Don't know if other languages have comparable "features".